# Understanding problem with conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let be $Y$ Beta$(\alpha, \beta )$ distributed random variable. Further more let $X$ conditional on $\{Y=y \}$ geometric distributed with paramter $y$.
>   Determine the distribution of X.

I know $Y$ is defined by the distribution function $$f_y=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$$ Further more I think $X$ conditional on $\{Y=y \}$ is given by $$f_{(x|y)}= 1-(1-y)^n$$ According to wikipedia $$f_{(x|y)}=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_y}$$
So $f_y \cdot f_{(x|y)}=f(x,y)$. This does not seem to be simplified easily. According to this one wants $f_x=f_{(y|x)} \cdot f(x,y)$. But one is not able to calculate $f_{(y|x)}$. Or what am I missing?

Comment: Once you get the joint distribution, you could calculate the marginal distribution of x (or calculate from conditional distribution directly - same formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for a marginal density is
$$
f_X(x) = \int_y f(x, y) dy = \int_y f_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y) f_Y(y) dy
$$
From the given information, we know that $Y$ is Beta distributed, so
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{y^{\alpha - 1}(1-y)^{\beta - 1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)}
$$
$f_{X\mid Y}$ is geometric with $Y$ as parameter, hence
$$
f_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y) = (1-y)^xy
$$
Thus the joint density becomes
$$
 f_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y) f_Y(y) = \frac{ y^{\alpha}(1-y)^{\beta - 1 + x} }{B(\alpha, \beta)}
$$
Now you're supposed to integrate out $y$, but this can be done easily by noting that the joint density is proportional to a Beta density with $\alpha^* = \alpha + 1$ and $\beta^* = \beta + x$, so you know that
$$
\int_y y^{\alpha}(1-y)^{\beta - 1 + x}  dy = B(\alpha + 1, \beta + x)
$$

Comment: so  finally we get $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta) \alpha \Gamma( \beta +x)}{\Gamma(\beta) \Gamma(\alpha +1 + \beta +x)}$ correct?

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm not sure how you got that $\alpha$ in the numerator, but yeah it should just be $\frac{ B(\alpha + 1, \beta + x)}{B(\alpha, \beta)}$.

Comment: I used $\Gamma(\alpha +1)=\Gamma(\alpha)\cdot \alpha$

Comment: @JohnDoe ah, right. Actually, $x$ is an integer so maybe it's possible to get rid of the gamma functions altoghether.

Comment: Why is x an integer? If so you are right, I might be able to simplify with using the gamma functional equation..because of the defintion of geometric distribution?

Comment: @JohnDoe because $X$ has geometric distribution. It's a discrete distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61475/discussion-between-john-doe-and-slug-pue).

Comment: Now I wanted to calculate $\mathbb E[X]$. Just bye using the defintion of mean I end up with an ugly integral. Are there any hidden tricks to use when working with beta distributions? Sorry for asking again..

Comment: @JohnDoe would be glad to help but you should make it a new question